# NodeJS - Passport-JWT, how to setup multiple extractors?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

Here is the configuration of my authentication strategy :

```
var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('MyBearer'),
  secretOrKey: SECRET,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  passReqToCallback: false
};
```

I would like to add a second extractor, if the first one fail, then I'd like to try the second one. To illustrate my idea, here is what I'd like to do :

```
var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  jwtFromRequest: [
    ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('MyBearer'),
    ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('authorization')
  ],
  secretOrKey: SECRET,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  passReqToCallback: false
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can also pass multiple extractor in ExtractJwt.fromExtractors function

```js
     var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {   
      secretOrKey: SECRET,   
      issuer : ISSUER,    
      audience: AUDIENCE,    
      passReqToCallback: false,
     jwtFromRequest:ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([ExtractJwt.fromBodyField('auth_token'),ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('auth_token')]),

};
```

Comment: Great! Didn’t try but I trust you. Thank you for replying even if the post was a little old, new solutions are always welcome, especially when that are closer to the original goal. Thumbs up man!

Comment: Just for precision, fromExtractors run every extractor until one return a valid token. It will not return an array of valid token as I thought  (I needed to get back multiple tokens at one but I misunderstood the usage of this.)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for sharing that simple solution. I adopted your approach for NestJs in typescript. Just in case someone looks for that.

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JWT_SECRET } from '../auth.constants';

/**
 * Extracts the jwt from a cookie
 * @param req Http Request
 */
const cookieExtractor = (req) => {
  let token = null;
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    token = req.cookies.jwt;
  }
  return token;
};

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  constructor(@Inject('JWT_SECRET') jwtSecret: string) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        // Take jwt from http header
        ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        // Take jwt from cookie
        cookieExtractor
      ]),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: { sub: number, iat: number, exp: number, username: string }): Promise<{ userId: any; username: any }> {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for contributing! The more answers the better!

Answer (score 3):

Just kidding!
I just realised that I could easily create [my own extractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt)!

```
var cookieExtractor = function(req) {
    var token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies)
    {
        token = req.cookies['jwt'];
    }
    return token;
};
```

Problem fixed!

**EDIT** : If your case is the same as mine, here is the code I made :

```
var TokenExtractor = function(req){
  var token = null;

  if ((req.headers && req.headers.authorization) || (req.query && req.query.authorization)) {
    if (req.headers.authorization)
      var parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    else if (req.query.authorization)
      var parts = req.query.authorization.split(' ');

    if (parts.length == 2) {
      var scheme = parts[0],
        credentials = parts[1];

      if (/^MyBearer$/i.test(scheme)) { //<-- replace MyBearer by your own.
        token = credentials;
      }
    }
  } else if (req.param('token')) {
    token = req.param('token');
    delete req.query.token;
  }

  return token;
}

var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  jwtFromRequest: TokenExtractor,
  secretOrKey: SECRET,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  passReqToCallback: false
};
```

This code is partly inspired by one you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/thesabbir/597be0ddd16e86e92f68#file-isauthorized-js).